# Java Generics: Question Type parameters inference in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am learning generics concept in Java.

In this particular line -> `class User<T extends List<U>, U>`, is there a reason why java forces for the second type param `U` in the class parameter definition when the first parameter itself defines `T<U>` or is there a shortcut that I am missing.

Calling code inside main:

```
    User<List<Integer>, Integer> u = new User<>("some_user", 21, l);
    System.out.println(u.getDetails());;
```

Class:

```
class User<T extends List<U>, U> {

private String name;
private int age;
private T details;

public User(String name, int age, T details) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.details = details;
}

}
```

Comment: The first parameter doesn't *define* `U`, it *uses* it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are declaring the type parameter `T` to have an upper bound `List<U>`, you haven't defined the type parameter `U` yet, so without a declaration of `U` it's not defined.

You can either do as you've done -- declare `U` second:

```
class User<T extends List<U>, U> {
```

or you can declare it first (the order doesn't matter):

```
class User<U, T extends List<U>> {
```

But unless you really need the specific type of `List`, I would remove that type parameter and focus on the type of the elements.

```
class User<U> {
    //...
    private List<U> details;

    public User(String name, int age, List<U> details) {
        //...
    }
}
```

(You can always just use `T` instead of `U` for the list element type.)